# DSVM can support SQL Server Developer Edition for Ubuntu

Tags: azure-dsvm

According to this
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/data-science-virtual-machine/tools-included#store-retrieve-and-manipulate-data,
it appears that the SQL Server Developer Edition (Ubuntu) is being supported in DSVM but I couldn’t find the name in the supported list here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/data-science-virtual-machine/dsvm-tools-data-platforms#sql-server-developer-edition,
furthermore there is no guide line for Linux Guide line but only windows guideline is there.
I’d like make sure the followings :

- Can DSVM support SQL Server Developer Edition for Ubuntu?
- If yes, where is the guideline for this?
- If no, the documentation is wrong? And any particular supporting plan for SQL Server Developer Edition for Ubuntu?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We don't preinstall SQL Server Developer Edition on the Ubuntu images but customers can install it on their own. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-ubuntu?view=sql-server-ver15) is the documentation and steps.

Thanks for bringing this up. We will update the documentation.

Enjoy,
Timo